# How to parse the HTML response in objective c

Tags: objective-c, html-parsing

I'm newbie to iPhone Development, I've an URL, which gives the response in the HTML. My requirement is to get the all Paragraph tags in the response. But am using TFHpple library and getting the particular xPath's data. But I need all the <p> tags data in the response. If any one knows please help me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

An objective c wrapper around libxml for parsing HTML
[Objective-C-HMTL-Parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)

Hpple: A nice Objective-C wrapper on the XPathQuery library for parsing HTML.
[Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)

Above is simple and handy libraries to use for html parsing with good documentation.

And a tutorial in this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Since sometimes the para tag has span and sometimes it does not, I would suggest trying to handle that by looping over the children

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSData  * data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
TFHpple * tutorialsParser       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];

NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//div[@id='NewsPageSubTitle']";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

for (TFHppleElement * element in tutorialsNodes) {
    NSLog(@"%@", element);
    NSLog(@"%@", [element tagName]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [element attributes]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [element children]);
    for (TFHppleElement *childElement in [element children]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", childElement);
    }
}
```